# Element by element concatenation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Say I have two lists:

```
header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
data_type = ['str', 'str', 'float64', 'float64']
```

How do I get a combined list like this:

```
data_type = {'a':str, 'b':str, 'c':float64, 'd':float64}
```

This is used to define `dtype` in `pd.read_csv` method.

Comment: `str`, without quotes?? (valid, but suspicious)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip

Comment: @KarolyHorvath and reverse: `float64` without quotes? valid?? maybe in pandas?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes in pandas.  Actually I just verified that both work (with or without). The original documentation doesn't have quotes that's why I didn't add quotes.  See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fastest:

```
header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
data_type = ['str', 'str', 'float64', 'float64']
dict(zip(header, data_type))
```

the idea is:
two lists merged with `zip` function(https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and than produced tuple of tuples converted to dictionary with `dict` function.

Comment: @JulienMarrec I'm sorry bro. I have no idea how it happened.

Comment: @JulienMarrec that cannot be 1 person that's for sure. Maybe because you answered the same thing after Andrey? `pandas` questions are sometimes harsh for pure python answerers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre actually at first his answer was only about dict comprehension, and since zip supposed to be more efficien(and maybe a bit more elegant) some users decided that it is not the best way. Anyway his answer is also right and I didn't downvote on it.

Comment: I had understood that you didn't. I avoid downvoting "concurrent" answers to mine, unless they're really bad/have misleading/wrong contents. BTW 5 upvotes for using `zip` that's really a good investment. My guess is that there are a lot of pandas specialists out there that don't know a lot of useful basic python stuff. Congrats.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, it was a bit unpredicatable :) Anyway I'm glad it is so helpful for folks here.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre  you're absolutely right.  A lot of people with a bit of R/Matlab background are turning to python these days.  They tend to take a programmatic approach and think in the old ways of whatever language they come from.  Bad and lazy habit indeed.  I'm just one of them...

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you actually want to return a datatype (python keyword) and not a string of a datatype, so I would use a dict comprehension with `eval`, this is how I would do it:

```
from numpy import float64
{header[i]:eval(data_type[i]) for i in range(len(header))}

{'a': str, 'b': str, 'c': numpy.float64, 'd': numpy.float64}
```

Also note that the dict comprehension option is slightly slower, at 1.91 µs per loop versus 1.62 µs per loop for the the dict+zip option

Comment: how the hell did this get 3 downvotes in 10 freaking secs?

Comment: I upvoted your answer just because it is not fair to get so much downvotes.

Comment: I also upvoted your answer because it helps clear a few concepts for me. My second week with python.

Comment: @LedgerYu also another way then:
`{k: data_type[i] for (i, k) in enumerate(header)}`. Using enumerate here for me looks more pythonic - and a little bit more transparent

Comment: upvoting because it seems to really answer the question. The question is unclear about data type of the str/float64 values.